# How to highlight entire column based on cell text using Pandas Excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I created an excel file using pandas ExcelWriter.

first 10 rows are test table
next 10 rows are prod table. 
both the tables have same column name and in same order.

I want to highlight the full column for a specific column name. How do I do that?

I was able to highlight full row based on conditions but now I want to highlight column based on column name.

Comment: If you're talking about Excel formatting, this will depend on which engine (i.e. Python package for writing Excel files) `ExcelWriter` is using .Currently, the default for [pandas 1.0.3](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) is `openpyxl`, but older version may use `xlrd`. Then read the documentation of the appropriate engine for details on how to add formatting.

Comment: xlsxwriter is the engine

Comment: I have no experience with `xlsxwriter`, but hopefully this page can help: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html